# Detecting encounters of trajectories in time

Tags: java, scala, machine-learning, spatial, proximity

I am looking for an efficient way of computing if two objects could have encountered. The data that describes that object movement (trajectory) are represented using ***x*** and ***y*** coordinates and ***timestamp***. An encounter is described as spatio-temporal proximity. That is, two objects are ***d*** meters away in the window of ***t*** seconds for some given ***d*** and ***t***. I have a large database of trajectories of different objects, where some data is sparser than the other.

What is the best algorithm to compute encounters and are there any Java/Scala libraries that would help?

**Edit:** Data describes movements of people. People may continuously walk, they may walk at different speeds and they may also stop. The data is represented only using ***x*** and ***y*** coordinates, ***timestamp*** and ***uid*** (id of a person). The data are only samples and are not the exact representation of trajectories; i.e. you should not assume that a person `id` moves from the point `p1` (associated with the time stamp `t1`) in a straight line to the point `p2`(associated with the time stamp `t2`) at a speed `distance(p1, p2) / (t2 - t1)`, where `t1` and `t2`  are two chronologically consecutive time stamps. Furthermore, the positions of people are not sampled at uniform rate.

Comment: are you freezing two elements at a time t and seeing whether they are at the same position or not.?, could you give specific data, it is impossible to help without knowing what is required and what is desired. there are physics libraries available.also, clarify whether you have coordinates of the objects position or its angle(trajectory) in your database

Comment: @Samlik some data samples and desired result for those samples would improve the question a lot. you will also need some kind of interpolation of position in time. straight line movement is a good initial assumption, which can be improved later if you manage to find a more realistic interpolation (e.g. learn trajectory probablilities from the same data array)